# FirefoxDriver() is not working - Selenium,Java

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, automation

I have started learning automation with Selenium in java.
I tried the same code in python and able to fetch contents from the website. But with java it throws "no suchmethod" error. I am using intellij and added selenium client and server 3.3.0. Firefox version 51.0.1.
Kindly help.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/sansui-190-l-direct-cool-single-door-refrigerator/product-reviews/itme94r4yqrbsge5?pid=RFRE94R3ZB5YHZZY");
    System.out.println("flipkart reviews");
    List<WebElement> reviews=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3DCdKt']"));
    for(WebElement review:reviews){
        System.out.println(review.getText());
    }
```

The error been thrown is the following.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V
[image]

Comment: [Check this](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2380), for example. It appears that you have the wrong Guava version the classpath.

Comment: i have added 19.0 version of Guava jar file..

Comment: You probably need Guava version 21 for Selenium 3.3.0.

Comment: added version 21 .. still throws same error..

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace and share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the entire code and the purpose of the code is fetch the webpage content. The same code works with other machine which has different version setup of selenium and firefox

Comment: The point is to see your complete project and the actual jar versions in the classpath.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of jar files added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `google-collections.jar` and `google-collections-0.8.jar` that are obsolete and were replaced by Guava. Remove these 2 jars and move `guava-21.jar` just below the `<Module source>`.

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks for the help ... The firefox browser is initiated and the data is fetched from the website now..